# PHP Send email form with multiple file upload to server

Tags: php, html, html-email, forms, http-post

I have some trouble getting below script right.

I get input from a form which contains below `<input>` for fileupload:

```
<form class="contactform" action="/php/mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" id="file-upload" name="uploaded_file[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
</form>
```

The multiple files should be stored into an array for upload into the created folder. The files should be validated before processing but that should first happen IF there are any files uploaded. If files have been uploaded one emailform should be processed messaging the filenames among other info. If not another emailform should be processed.

A little session is created to process some info to "confirm"-page.

Below script seems to only process the later emailform regardless what I do.

I am using PHP 5.6.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Settings
$max_allowed_file_size = 2048; // size in KB

//$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "pdf", "png");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$modtager = "simon@stutteri-volstrup.dk";
$recipient = $modtager;

//Get values from from
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$hesteid = $_POST['hesteid'];
$hestenavn = $_POST['hestenavn'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

//Session variables
$_SESSION["sname"] = $name;
$_SESSION["semail"] = $email;
$_SESSION["sphone"] = $phone;


if (empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    //Upload folder
    //name for mail

    $d = date('y.m.d');
    $varfoldername = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/receivedfiles/" . $d . " " . $name . "/";
    $varemailfoldername ="/" . $d ." " . $name . "/";
    if(!is_dir($varfoldername)) 
    {
        mkdir($varfoldername , 0777 , true);
    }
    $upload_folder = $varfoldername;
    $emailupload_folder = $varemailfoldername;

    //Uploaded file
    // Loop through each file
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ )
    {
        //Get the uploaded file information

        $name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$i]);

        //Validations

        //Validate size requirements
        $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"][$i]/1024;//size in KBs

        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size)
        {
            die("Fejl: Filen er for stor");
        }
        else
        {
            $sizecheck = true;
        }

        //------ Validate the file extension -----
        //get the file extension of the file
        $type_of_uploaded_file =
        substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
        strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
        $allowed_ext = false;
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
        {
            if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
            {
                $allowed_ext = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                $ext_check = true;
            }
        }

        if(!$allowed_ext)
        {
            die("The uploaded file is not supported file type. \n Send venligst filer af følgende type: jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp, pdf");
        }

        //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
        $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
        $emailpath_of_uploaded_file = $emailupload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
        $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"][$i];

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
        {
            if($sizecheck || $ext_check)
            {
                move_uploaded_file ( $tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file );
            }
        }

    else
    {
        die("Error while copying the uploaded file");}
    }

    //Send email
    $formcontent=" Fra: $email \n Firma: $company \n Navn: $name \n Adresse: $adress , $areacode \n Land: $land \n Telefon: $phone \n Ringes op: $call \n Type: $type \n Hoppens navn og ID: $hestenavn , $hesteid \n Besked: \n $message \n \n Vedhæftede filer: \n array($emailpath_of_uploaded_file)";
    $subject = "Besked fra hjemmesiden fra $name";
    $mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header('Location: https://www.homepage.com');
}
else 
{
    $emailpath_of_uploaded_file = "Ingen";
    //Send email
    $formcontent=" Fra: $email \n Firma: $company \n Navn: $name \n Adresse: $adress , $areacode \n Land: $land \n Telefon: $phone \n Ringes op: $call \n Type: $type \n Hoppens navn og ID: $hestenavn , $hesteid \n Besked: \n $message \n \n Vedhæftede filer: \n $emailpath_of_uploaded_file";
    $subject = "Besked fra hjemmesiden fra $name";
    $mailheader = "Fra: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    header('Location: https://www.homepage.com');
}
?>
```

Comment: A little indentation and a few functions would go a long way to make this more readable/debuggable. It's also somewhat unclear what your problem is exactly.

Comment: I have indented. The problem is that no file is uploaded to server. The script just proces as there is no file uploaded.

Comment: Your code to handle the uploaded file(s) is only executed when `if (empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']))` is true. But when this is true, there are no files?

Comment: The files comes from a HTML form before this. For my understanding the `empty()` returns true if the the array is empty. Yet changing the if statements doesn't make it work either.

Comment: Did you set enctype="multipart/form-data" inside your form tags? 
(this might be a stupid answer, but figure it was worth asking)

Comment: Do you have the proper encoding type tag/attribute on the form in the HTML code?

Comment: @dustbuster I should have included my formtags and so I did. Yes, I use that enctype setting.

Comment: @ivanivan I just did and yes I should have the proper encoding.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure! I'll review your script!